# How can I display row data in an rldc report page header and footer

Tags: c#, header, report, footer

Update - I just realized that it cannot be done in the page header and footer areas.

I am designing a report in visual studio 2013 and wanted to display portions of the row/record data in the tablix header and footer areas as well as the detail area.  The tablix header is displaying in all the pages, and that's okay with me.  I have inserted rows above the tablix header to contain fields that come with the row. I have set the static property KeepTogether to True and KeepWithGroup to After.  But although the fields in the Details section changes for each page, the fields placed in the header area doesn't change.  I am displaying row/record per page.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can do it, but you would have to refer to text boxes and their values in header/footer, not your data source values.

Alternatively, use tables and their header/footer and/or table groups header/footer.